# Autonumber with alternating number and letters

Tags: c#

I want an auto-numbering class in c# which would generate numbers of 8 digit length in the following format i.e. **1A2B3C4D**..**one number followed by one letter**.Any suggestions??

Comment: What have you tried, what was the issue you had? What are the rules for the number, must it be unique or random or consecutive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudocode for generating such string:

```
String result = "";
for ( int i = 0; i < 8 ; i++) 
{
if ( i % 2 == 0)
{
// random(a,b) returns random value between or equal to a-b
   result.append(random(0,9).toString());
}
else
{
   result.append(random(65,90).toChar()); // Generating a random value between 65-90 (A-Z in ascii)
}
}
```

Edit:

Or as Sayse suggested:

```
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i< 4; i++)
{
  result.append(random(0,9).toString());
  result.append(random(65-90).toChar());
}
```

Comment: the if statement can be removed completely and just append twice (and half the for iteration count

Comment: Performance wasn't my concern. CRM_user seems to be a beginner and it may be easier for him to read that way.

Comment: I would think two appends would be easier to understand than understanding the `%` operator. Either way its a pretty nice pseudo